# Uploading Files as part of a form submission in nextjs 13.4 app router (client to server action) has all properties but files are {} at server side

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, react-hook-form

i am using nextjs 13.5 app router. i have a componenet 'upload product' which is using react-hook-form and schadzn ui form. this is using validation by zod and my schema for this is :

```
export const createProductSchema = z.object({
  name : z.string().min(3).max(50),
  description : z.string().min(3).max(500),
  disabled : z.boolean().default(false),
  isOrganic : z.boolean().default(false),
  category : z.string(),
  image : z
    .any()
    .refine((file) => file?.size <= MAX_FILE_SIZE, `Max image size is 5MB.`)
    .refine(
      (file) => ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES.includes(file?.type),
      "Only .jpg, .jpeg, .png and .webp formats are supported."
    ),
  image2 :z
  .any()
  .refine((file) => file?.size <= MAX_FILE_SIZE, `Max image size is 5MB.`)
  .refine(
    (file) => ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES.includes(file?.type),
    "Only .jpg, .jpeg, .png and .webp formats are supported."
  ).nullable().optional(),
  image3 : z
  .any()
  .refine((file) => file?.size <= MAX_FILE_SIZE, `Max image size is 5MB.`)
  .refine(
    (file) => ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES.includes(file?.type),
    "Only .jpg, .jpeg, .png and .webp formats are supported."
  ).nullable().optional(),
```

in my form

```
 const form = useForm<Inputs>({
        resolver: zodResolver(createProductSchema),
        defaultValues: {
            name: "",
            description: "",
            price: "",
            category: "",
            storageType: "",
            size : "small",
            quantity: 1,
           image: "", //new File([], ''),
            image2: "",//new File([], ''),
            image3: "",//new File([], ''),
```

now the first error i see frequently is when i am trying to initialise this with default values, i cant assign the image as a specific value. i have tried the new File([], '') but it seems to only work sometimes and when i use validation like above it does not work.

secondly when i submit this form, all fields are correct. this includes the image data on the client side. when i pass this to my server component. all fields are present as they should be but the files are empty objects, that just have {} in them.

i am not to sure what i need to do in order to include files to pass over. A solution that i have working is to introduce a new FormData object and pass the images separately to my component, but that seems not the best practice to be doing, especially when i am submitting a form anyway...

```
    startTransition(async () => {
            try{
                debugger;

   / this surely cant be the way to do it ??     /
                const images = new FormData();
                images.append('image', values.image);
                images.append('image2', values.image2! ?? null);
                images.append('image3', values.image3! ?? null);


                const product = await createProductAction(values, images);
                if(product){
```

```
export async function createProductAction(
    input : z.infer<typeof createProductSchema>, files : FormData -<<< can see files with this 
)
```

any help would be appreaciated :)

thanks

passing formData as a separate object to contain the files.